# Browser side cookie issue

Tags: django, cookies

I am creating a cookie to store some data( how many times the user visited a page)in the client side. Here I am trying to understand the client side cookie. I am able to achieve the desired result using a server side cookie. But in this client side cookie set up every time I visit the page the cookie count is not increasing. Below is the cookie code in my Django view, Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

def index(request):

```
if 'visited' in request.COOKIES:
    visited = int(request.COOKIES['visited'])
    visited += 1
    response = render(request,'index.html',context={'visited':visited})
else :
    response = render(request,'index.html',context={'visited':0})
    response.set_cookie('visited',1)

return response
```

## modified the code as below to solve the issue,

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    visited = 0
    resopnse = render(request,'index.html',{'visited':visited})
    if 'visited' in request.COOKIES:
        visited = int(request.COOKIES['visited'])
        visited += 1
    response = render(request,'index.html',{'visited':visited})
    response.set_cookie('visited',visited)
    return response
```

Comment: Why are you not setting the value `visited` in the cookie
 - `response.set_cookie('visited',visited)` in the if condition?

Comment: If block executes if the cookie already exists, I am creating the cookie in else condition and setting it's value to 1. In subsequent calls only if will be executed and it should increment the value.

Comment: I solved the issue by modifying the code . Please check the added content in original post under the heading "modified the code as below to solve the issue,"  to see how the new solution looks.

Comment: That is what I suggested. `response.set_cookie('visited',visited)` should be called for both the conditions.

Comment: Thank you Nihal. I was not very clear so took some time to understand it.